# Add custom column to Users admin panel

Tags: admin

There is default 5 columns named Username Name Email Role Posts in USERS.
Now I want to add one more column with his contact number.

How can I achieve this??

[image: Here where black box is shown]

Comment: Do you have phone number setup? I mean can your user add phone numbers in their profile?

Comment: no .. I just want to know how to add .. its not fix that contact number only .. its can b just a blank column also

Comment: If your site had a lot of custom columns, you might be interested in a plugin called Admin Columns.

Comment: you can see this blog with detailed explanation http://tekina.info/add-extra-column-user-listing-page-wordpress-admin-panel/

Comment: For the non-coders, there is a plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). (Google leads to this page, too. Newbies might not know all plugins of WordPress)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Ok, Here is the code to allow your users to add phone numbers. Paste this full code in functions.php file. This will add new field on user profile for "Phone Number" and add a column user table on WordPress admin for phone.

```
function new_contact_methods( $contactmethods ) {
    $contactmethods['phone'] = 'Phone Number';
    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'new_contact_methods', 10, 1 );


function new_modify_user_table( $column ) {
    $column['phone'] = 'Phone';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table' );

function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'phone' :
            return get_the_author_meta( 'phone', $user_id );
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```

**EDIT**

To add two columns you need to make some changes. Compare both codes to understand.

```
function new_modify_user_table( $column ) {
    $column['phone'] = 'Phone';
    $column['xyz'] = 'XYZ';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table' );

function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'phone' :
            return get_the_author_meta( 'phone', $user_id );
        case 'xyz' :
            return '';
        default:
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Use code again. I changed it so you can see phone field on user list too.

Comment: Great! worked ..
But at the time of adding user why are they not asking for Phone Number ?

Comment: Can you please explain this code ? I want to add one more field but it is showing me an error.

Comment: Check edits in above code. You can add as many columns as you want.

Comment: I would suggest this be added to a [site-specific plugin](http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-site-specific-snippets-plugin/) since it has nothing to do with the theme's appearance.

Comment: thanks Robert .. you helped me a lot !!
can you just tell me last thing .. what is 10 & 3 in the last line of the code ..

Comment: That is priority and accepted args. Check docs on add_filter here, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: If it is a commercial (free or paid) theme then please don't put this code in theme's functions.php. Because, you can lose these changes if theme is updated. Make a small plugin for this.

Comment: what's the $return?

Comment: Yes why there is a `return $return` at the end, please? could you explain it?

Comment: Finally `$user = get_userdata( $user_id );` and `return $return` are absolutely **not** necessary. Variable `$user` is not used by the function and `$return` is not defined so it is returning nothing.

Comment: hey @Robert hue thanks for the working code. I have one question. I don't see this column in my DB wp_users table. Why?

Comment: I am getting nothing from in this fucntion new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) , Can you please let me know why?

Comment: @Roberthue is there a way to re-order the column?

Comment: ah found it [here](http://codepixelz.com/web-design/how-to-add-new-column-on-user-listing-of-wordpress-dashboard/).

Comment: Really nitpicky but we probably don't need the break; as we are doing a return on the lines above. Thanks for posting though - really helped.

Comment: Is it better, me thinks, to put this code in a plugin or /wp-admin rather than a theme-specific folder? If left in a theme-specific folder such as functions.php, it would quite likely get overridden when the theme is updated.