# Backend users list - add Woocommerce meta to table

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm a little new to Wordpress/Woocommerce but am fumbling my way through...

We have Woocommerce installed and working where we request billing address and billing phone number (amongst other things) and I am trying to show this data on the backend users (view all) table as it currently only pulls its data from the base Wordpress registrations details, not from Woocommerce.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
This is where I am hoping to add some extra columns using Woocommerce details.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: hello can you include a screenshot of where you like the info to show on wordpress backend just so i can be clear of your question.

Comment: Hi there, updated original post.

Comment: You could just use the answer given in the post that you took that screenshot away from. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160422/add-custom-column-to-users-admin-panel

Otherwise look at the Admin Columns plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom column to Users admin panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160422/add-custom-column-to-users-admin-panel)

Comment: I agree it's close to a duplicate however isn't that response using the content from the first step of the solution? The first step adds the form to the registration page of a standard wordpress install. My understanding is this content is already there as it's built into the Woocommerce billing form so what I am asking is how do I get data from that form? Step two of that solution pulls data from the newly created form content.

Answer (score 0):

All the code below is for your current theme `functios.php`
 file (but better use a child theme or a custom plugin).

### Step 1.

Not sure if you figured out with adding the columns, but I will mention it too - use `manage_users_columns` hook.

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table' );
function new_modify_user_table( $columnnames ) {
    return array_slice( $columnnames, 0, 3, true )
    + array( 'billing_address' => 'Billing Address' )
    + array_slice( $columnnames, 3, NULL, true );
}
```

`array_slice()` function is required because we're adding the column on the 3rd place in the table.

### Step 2.

It is time to use `manage_users_custom_column` hook to add the data to the column. So, we're adding billing address and phone.

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );
function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'billing_address' :
            $val = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', true ) . '<br />';
            $val .= get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', true );
            break;
    }
    return $val;
}
```

If you're looking for how to get the complete billing address information (state, country etc), look at [this code example](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/columns.html#billing_details_column).