# How can i attach the attachment-ID to the user profile image?

Tags: theme-development, uploads

I have used custom php form for uploading image via ajax. And has successfully uploaded the image and getting the attachment id & the image url also,

Is there any way to attach the attachment id or the image url to the user profile image, so the admin can also view the user profile image in user list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you can add the attachment ID to the user's profile using the [User Meta API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/working-with-user-metadata/), then display the image using the `show_user_profile` and `edit_user_profile` hooks.

Adding the image to the user listing can be done using the `manage_users_columns` and `manage_users_custom_column` filters, which Robert hue covered in this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/160423/2807

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ACF-fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for this. And then add and attachment-ID to the user. This way, you don't have to check if the user has a profile-image or not, so you avoid some annoying dependency-constraint-issues.

If you do so, then you can use the plugin: [Admin Columns Pro](https://www.admincolumns.com/), to show that in a column in the admin.