# Adding a dropdown on the user admin

Tags: plugin-development, users

I all I'm following this: [Add custom column to Users admin panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160422/add-custom-column-to-users-admin-panel)

I need to add a dropdown in the user page (**plus+ if I can create the dropdown with values from ACF**).

The dropdown would be for a department. Right now I am trying a way I found on here, but it only adds a text field.
[EDIT]

I need the function to add a user (they will sign up), that will show 2 dropdowns added to the register screen (front end template) and to save those values.

Dropdowns are location and department. I think I know how to build the dropdowns, how would I save those values so they're attached to a user?

[/EDIT]

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: What does the dropdown do? Is it just a filter? Can you edit your question to include more information? There aren't many specifics, what have you tried so far? I'm pretty sure there are lots of questions asking how to do this with good answers on the site already

Comment: @TomJNowell Can you point me to similar questions? Sometimes I'm not sure what to search for. ~ Justin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.